# Enterprise architect javascript object error element type

Tags: javascript, object, enterprise-architect

When I get element type, I can't ask if element is Class:

```
var theElement as EA.Element;
theElement = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();

If (theElement.Type=="Class"){}
```

I get error "Object was expected". Also tried to create string variable, but didnt work... Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeSelectedObject()` does not necessarily return an `EA.Element`.
It could be `EA.Diagram`, `EA.Package`, `EA.Attribute`,...

You should first check whether the returned object is not null.
Then you can use `theElement.ObjectType` to distinguish between the different object types

See also http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/objecttypeenum.html